# Landscape media queries for iPad Pro 12.9 not working

Tags: css

I have used the below media query CSS code but in iPad Pro 12.9 it's not working somehow. Below is the code:

```
/* Landscape */
@media only screen
   and (min-device-width : 1024px)
   and (max-device-width : 1366px)
   and (orientation : landscape) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen
   and (min-device-width: 1024px)
   and (max-device-width: 1366px)
   and (orientation: landscape)
   and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
}

/* Landscape */
 @media only screen and (min-device-width: 1366px) 
     and (max-device-height: 1024px) 
     and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
     and (orientation: landscape) {
}
```

I have referred following solutions but somehow it is not working for me.

- [CSS Media Queries for iPad Pro](https://identifywebdesign.co.uk/css-media-queries-for-the-ipad-pro/)
- [Correct Media Queries for iPad Pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978487/correct-media-query-for-ipad-pro)
- [iPad specific CSS](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/ipad-specific-css/)

Can someone help me here to make this one effective for iPad Pro 12.9 inches?

Comment: What exactly is not working? These are the right media queries.

Comment: Please see [ask]. Ideally you want to show what you tried and explain what was unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1366px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1366px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@media only screen 
   and (min-device-width: 1024px) 
   and (max-device-width: 1366px) 
   and (orientation: landscape) 
   and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
 }
```