# CSS state for iPad Pro cursor hover

Tags: html, css, ios, ipad, ipados

The new cursor on iPad Pro aims to fit buttons when hovered. Is there a state used in safari to create special hover for it ?

I would like to make a button looks like this on a website :

[image: iPad Pro cursor fitting button on hover]

Right now, hover state works but the cursor dot doesn’t disappear to fit the button.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Did you try this? Add a `{ cursor: none; }` style on hover.

Comment: @CuteShaun Thanks for your answer, I just tried it and it doesn’t seem to work... It would have been a solution except that it would also have affected computer users.

Comment: weird, it should be work, try clear cache on your iPad. You can specify your styles only on iPads, try for this media-queries, it's for iPad & iPad mini: 

`
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
`

Comment: @CuteShaun I tried on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/uCwfB) each states and here is the [video result](https://imgur.com/a/6WJm0yM). I think iPad Pro has larger viewport than 1024px.

Comment: try this for iPad Pro: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978487/what-is-correct-media-query-for-ipad-pro

Comment: @CuteShaun nice, I did not know this was possible ! But `cursor: none;` still has no effect on iPad cursor (as shown on the video)..

Comment: hmm, try {cursor: none !important;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Apple doesn’t let you change the iPadOS cursor appearance using the `cursor` property. There’s currently no way to interact with the iPadOS cursor other than reacting to `:hover`, `:active`, etc. pseudo-selectors. You can’t control the visibility or appearance of the cursor itself. It you want to simulate the iPadOS cursor hover appearance for devices other than the iPad, check out this CodePen: https://codepen.io/cezzre/pen/poJxLEM