# IPad Media Query Changes Desktop

Tags: css, ipad, mobile, sass, desktop

I have problem with IPad media in landscape mode. Is it possible to point out that these rules are only for mobile ? It`s happens beacouse of max-width in landscape mode. Here is my media

```
 @media (max-width:1366px) and (max-height:1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
     background-size: 200%;
     background-position: 50% 50%;
 }
```

We solved the problem if someone need here is link to all @media

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Could you describe what the problem is? Also I don't understand "Is it possible to point out that these rules are only for mobile ?"

Comment: I mean that rule changes background also for desktop. I don`t won`t that. I wanna only change background for IPad in landscape. I don`t know how to set it beacouse desktop also have 1366px. Sorry for my English

Comment: You could use a media query to see if the device can hover or has a pointer, but it will probably lead to false positive.

Comment: Thanks for the description, understood. Does this help? [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978487/what-is-correct-media-query-for-ipad-pro